# avr if statement optimization for speed or size

Tags: c, optimization, if-statement, avr

Hy there everyone!

I'm doing good progress on my AVR for my DIY sprinkler and fish tank automatization, but I've come across a question, that bugs me.

Which if statement runs on the AVR faster?(in less clock cycles)
By how much?

```
if(temp_sensor[0] < -20)
{
    OCR1A--;
}
else if(tempout > tempset)
{
    OCR1A--;
}
```

Or

```
if((temp_sensor[0] < -20) || (tempout > tempset))
{
    OCR1A--;
}
```

On second thought, my second question is: 
Which one uses less space?

My conclusion:
First of all, thanks everyone for your answers and comments!

The primary objective should be to write a clean code, that is easy to understand.

Comment: I guess you mean || in the second one. And also missing ) after -20.

Comment: Don't try to do over optimization. Write clean and readable C code and let the compiler do the optimization for you. It will do it better than you. If you really need super optimized code, then write it in ASM. It is the only way to manage the clock cycle consumption of your code.

Comment: I doubt you are CPU limited by any means, and why worry about the if statement when the temp sensor which I guess you hooked up using the ADC or OneWire will take thousands of cycles to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way

```
if((temp_sensor[0] < -20) || (tempout > tempset))
{
    OCR1A--;
}
```

is better way to write these kind of conditions. it is more understandable. as to if it takes less ticks it's not really significant, unless you do it hundred of thousand of times, and in this case just check them both and see which is better

Answer (score 3):

You could try for a (seemingly) jumpless approach:

```
const int8_t delta = temp_sensor < -20 || tempout > tempset;
OCR1A -= delta;
```

That can sometimes give shorter code. Of course it's very CPU-dependent, not sure how well the AVR likes code like this. It very well might generate a jump for the short-circuiting of the `||` operator, too. It's also totally possible for the compiler to optimize itself out of the jumps all on its own.

Comment: +1 for mentioning CPU dependency. On the AVR you don't have a "conditional execution" mechanism as in ARM for example. Hence you will end up most probably with test, branch if fulfilled, test branch if not fulfilled or something similar in that case. Which is very likely what the compiler produces for any of the proposal i've seen for this question. So I'd stick with @LtWorf's opinion: Write for maintainability. Leave cycle fiddling to the compiler. If cylce fiddling is important, write the assembly yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Write code for readability, not for speed. Especially in those very trivial cases where the compiler can easily figure out what is happening and optimize it.

You should avoid the 1st way because you have some duplicated code in it, which isn't ideal.

Also I must point out that unless optimized, an || or an &&, are compiled to branch instructions the same way an if statement is, so they do improve readability in the code but don't really bring any performance advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to *unwind*, you can also use it this way:

```
OCR1A -= (uint8_t)((temp_sensor < -20) | (tempout > tempset));
```

`|`  is bitwise OR.

This will remove the `JUMP` code required for Logical OR (`||`).